# How to provide private validation service to external clients?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, web-services, architecture

We have some private algorithm for validating some data. Also we have many clients-shops who send us this data. Now clients ask us to provide this private algorithm to cut the number of errors. We can't provide this algorithm in open format. So my question is how to provide validation service for clients without possibility to see it? Now I see only webservice. Does anybody have other ideas?

Comment: Why does the algorithm has to remain private? Often, it is data (e.g. private keys) which is private.. Did you consider publishing the algorithm under an opensource license?

Comment: Clients send us data, e.g. some key and we validate it. If we open algorithm then clients can determine need data sequence and fake key and send us data which won't be able send other clients who will send right data

Comment: You could design it otherwise. See for instance SSH or other cryptographic techniques. The code is public, but data stays secure & private.

Answer (score 0):

If users can call a web service then I guess this would be a good and simple solution but if users want a local solution then may be you can write a simple program which contains your algorithm and give it to users so that they can directly validate their data using given program. You don't need to provide raw algorithm instead you can encapsulate it in some program/exe

Answer (score 0):

You can create an application and then Obfuscate the code. This would allow you to send the application to the clients and they would not be able to view the algorithm. The other option is a service which they can utilize. I would look at utilizing Windows Azure if performance is an issue.

Comment: Ofuscation is not secure. Giving the code to other parties eventually allows for decoding it. Its a matter of energy put in by a client.